# imprimir el elemento de una pila anterior

Tags: java

tengo una duda como puedo imprimir el objeto anterior , para ponerlos en contexto pondre lo que tengo que hacer para ser mas claro.

En un navegador de Internet, se puede guardar el historial de paginas
web visitadas en una pila. De esta manera se puede volver al enlace
de la página anterior con una simple operación de desapilar()

• Realice los métodos de adelante y atrás de un navegador

tengo los siguientes metodos que es lo que pide  tengo una clase pagina con los atributos nombre y url y una clase

```
public class NavegadoWeb {
    Stack<Pagina> pilaUno = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Pagina> pilados = new Stack<>();

 public void adelante(Pagina p) {
        if (pilados.empty()) {
            pilaUno.push(p);
        } else {
            pilaUno.push(pilados.pop());
        }
    }

    public void irAtras() {
        pilados.push(pilaUno.pop());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        NavegadoWeb nV = new NavegadoWeb();
        nV.adelante(new Pagina("Facebook", "https:/www.facebook.com"));
        nV.adelante(new Pagina("YOUTUBE", "https:/www.youtube.com"));
        nV.adelante(new Pagina("GOOGLE", "https:/www.google.com"));
        nV.adelante(new Pagina("UFPS", "https:/www.ufps.com"));
        nV.irAtras();
        nV.pagina(); // imprimi el elemento que esta en la cima de la pilaUno

    }

pero quisiera cunado llame al metodo "irAtrar()" me imprima el objeto o en este caso seria la pagina aterior como podria realizar esa accion ? gracias de ante mano
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por diseño el método `irAtras()` solo debería hacer eso, ir atrás. Y el obtener la página actual debe hacerse con otro método, por ejemplo:

```
public void mostrarPaginaActual(){
       System.out.println(pilaUno.peek());
    }
```

Se usa el método `peek()` para devolver el último elemento en la pila sin removerlo.

Para que se imprima la información de la clase `Pagina`, esta debe sobre escribir el método `toString()` así:

```
public class Pagina {
    String url;
    String pagina;


    public Pagina(String pagina, String url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.pagina  = pagina;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pagina{" +
                "url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", pagina='" + pagina + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más sencillo es que en `irAtras()` devuelvas la página hacia la que estás yendo:

```
public String irAtras() {
    String pagina = pilaUno.pop();
    pilados.push(pagina);
    return pagina;
}
```

Y luego en el main:

```
System.out.println("Vamos a " + nv.irAtras());
```